# Edeliver and systemd for Phoenix/Elixir applications

Tags: linux, elixir, phoenix-framework, systemd

Here's how I'm deploying my Phoenix/Elixir application on a server:

```
mix edeliver stop production --verbose
mix edeliver build release --verbose
mix edeliver deploy release to production --verbose
mix edeliver start production --verbose
```

It works as long as it's being run this way.

I've created a systemd unit for my website. I've checked it -- it's working fine, start and stop. Then I've deployed my website, the service which was running, isn't running anymore, it's in the failure state, where the website itself is running -- that's not how it should be.

How can I incorporate my systemd unit-service into these 4 commands above for deploy? That is, edeliver should run and stop the service for my website **via systemd** by "sudo systemctl start|stop my_website" somehow. Or is there other way?

Comment: I think the idea is that the new release is built and deployed while production is still running before using `mix edeliver restart production`, avoiding downtime.

Answer (score 2):

`edeliver` uses the [`upstart` scripts hardcoded](https://github.com/boldpoker/edeliver/blob/990ee09e75140697c4ec9e97662b6f0d9f74ef88/libexec/common#L287). That said, it simple executes `sudo stop blah` on remote.

There probably are better and more robust solutions, but I personally  overcame this by setting aliases for my deploy user on remote:

```
alias start='systemctl enable'
alias stop='systemctl disable'
```